# Annoying Square Where Scrollbars Meet

Tags: .net, wpf

I have an app with a ScrollViewer. Where the 2 scrollbars meet is an annoying little square (see img below) I am trying to get rid of.  When I "Snoop" the app I can find it as a "Rectangle" but I assume its part of the ScrollViewer?

I have searched and search for any info on this but all I can find are suggestions to hide it by placing something over the top of it :s

Can anyone point me in the right direction to sort this?

[image: Annoying Little Square]

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="HorizontalScrollBar" 
        TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
        <Grid >
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="18"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.00001*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="18"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Border
                Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                CornerRadius="2" 
                Background="Transparent"   />
            <RepeatButton 
                Grid.Column="0"                           
                Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarLineButton}"
                Width="18"
                Command="ScrollBar.LineLeftCommand"
                Content="M 4 0 L 4 8 L 0 4 Z" />
            <Track 
                Name="PART_Track"
                Grid.Column="1"
                IsDirectionReversed="False">
                <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                    <RepeatButton 
                        Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarPageButton}"
                        Command="ScrollBar.PageLeftCommand" />
                </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                <Track.Thumb>
                    <Thumb 
                        Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarThumb}" 
                        Margin="0,1,0,1"  
                        Background="{DynamicResource NormalBrush}"
                        BorderBrush="{DynamicResource NormalBorderBrush}" />
                </Track.Thumb>
                <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                    <RepeatButton 
                        Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarPageButton}"
                        Command="ScrollBar.PageRightCommand" />
                </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
            </Track>
            <RepeatButton 
                Grid.Column="3" 
                Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarLineButton}"
                Width="18"
                Command="ScrollBar.LineRightCommand"
                Content="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 0 8 Z"/>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: How are you getting the scrollbar to color?

Comment: I am by no means expert in WPF and I cannot say I understand everything fully but as far as I can see its coming from this control template

Comment: Probably not what is breaking it but the Grid.Column="3" is out of range.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Blam but as you say it didn't help the problem.  I can't believe something so simple can be so annoying!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't fully style a ListBox/Scrollviewer in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944633/cant-fully-style-a-listbox-scrollviewer-in-wpf)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I was just having the exact same problem, but found this answer here on Stack to solve it for me:

[Can't fully style a ListBox/Scrollviewer in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944633/cant-fully-style-a-listbox-scrollviewer-in-wpf)

Although **that** solution **does** put something in place of the square, it's done in the ControlTemplate (of the **ScrollViewer**, not the ScrollBar) rather than via some bubble-gum-patching approach of putting something on top of the ScrollViewer **control**.

However, I found that by just omitting the Rectangle definition from that template altogether, the annoying corner square just goes away - i.e. that area takes on whatever the background color of the ScrollViewer is (which, in the example given, is transparent - and that suits me fine. If you want to set the color of the ScrollViewer background, just set the Background property of the Grid).

So try adding this to your Resource:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <ScrollContentPresenter Grid.Column="0" />
                    <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Value="{TemplateBinding VerticalOffset}" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}"/>
                    <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Value="{TemplateBinding HorizontalOffset}" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"/>
                    <!--<Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Fill="Red"/>-->
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: For future reference if you have a multi-line block of code to include in an answer it's much more readable if you select it and click the button with the `{}` to apply code formatting to the entire block rather than using back ticks since back ticks don't format as nicely

Comment: This has been driving me crazy!  Thanks d7samurai that has fixed my problem perfectly. I will sleep at night again now!

Answer (score 5):

I have a custom control that needs the ViewportWidth and ViewportHeight of ScrollViewer. But the answered overrided style broke that part.

So maybe an easy way.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
        <Style.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
        </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

The Rectangle Fill property is set to SystemColors.ControlBrushKey in the default Template

Comment: Thanks, this was all that was really needed in 2020. The other answer caused the ScrollViewer to not scroll anymore sometimes.

Comment: @Daryll Just wanted to confirm that overriding the ScrollViewer style of a richtextbox does indeed break vertical scrolling. I've found no work around. The above example does indeed work to circumvent this.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to remove empty space use following code:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <ScrollContentPresenter Grid.Column="0" />
                    <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Value="{TemplateBinding VerticalOffset}" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}"/>
                    <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Value="{TemplateBinding HorizontalOffset}" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: How is your answer different from the accepted one posted 2 years ago?

Comment: In my answer I used ColumnSpan for horizontal scrollbar. That's why blank space disappears. If you'd like to fill it with vertical scrollbar just remove ColumnSpan and add RowSpan on vertical scrollbar.

Answer (score -1):

The marked answer didn't do it right for me.  This one did.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Panel.Background}">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <!--<Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Fill="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}" />-->
                    <ScrollContentPresenter Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="{TemplateBinding Control.Padding}" Content="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.Content}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.ContentTemplate}" CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll}" />
                    <ScrollBar Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Minimum="0" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.ScrollableHeight}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.ViewportHeight}" Value="{Binding Path=VerticalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}" Cursor="Arrow" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="VerticalScrollBar" />
                    <ScrollBar Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Minimum="0" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.ScrollableWidth}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.ViewportWidth}" Value="{Binding Path=HorizontalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" Cursor="Arrow" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="HorizontalScrollBar" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```